# Android 5.1.1 won't install apps [re asked]

Tags: root-access

I have a Alcatel onetouch model 50540 running android 5.1.1 as in the title. it is rooted and began uninstalling pre-installed bloatware on my device. I do not have a complete list of uninstalled apps because I had only kept track after the first few, but ill list the ones I do know about

Download Manager
Downloads
Talkback
Hangouts
Cricket Wi-Fi Manager
Camera
Email
Onetouch Launcher
That is the essence of what I did. I do have an edited hosts file as a makeshift adblock.

Play store gives me an error code 0 to which I removed app data and tried again, same problem.

I have tried installing local apps which brings up an "app not installed" box.

Lastly I have tried do directly extract the app into /data/app and rebooting which didn't work.[image][image]